# Codename One EasyThread implementation that repeats a runnable if its result is false

Tags: codenameone

*Note for the readers: this question is specific for Codename One only.*

I'm developing an app that needs some initial data from a server to run properly. The first shown Form doesn't need this data and there is also a splash screen on the first run, so if the Internet connection is good there is enought time to retrive the data... but the Internet connection can be slow or absent.

I have in the `init` a call to this method:

```
private void getStartData() {
    Runnable getBootData = () -> {
        if (serverAPI.getSomething() && serverAPI.getXXX() && ...) {
            isAllDataFetched = true;
        } else {
            Log.p("Connection ERROR in fetching initial data");
        }
    };
    EasyThread appInfo = EasyThread.start("APPINFO");
    appInfo.run(getBootData);
}
```

Each `serverAPI` method in this example is a synchronous method that return `true` if success, `false` otherwise. My question is how to change this EasyThread to repeat again all the calls to `(serverAPI.getSomething() && serverAPI.getXXX() && ...)` **after one second** if the result is `false`, and again after another second and so on, until the result is `true`.

I don't want to shown an error or an alert to the user: I'll show an alert only if the static boolean `isAllDataFetched` is `false` when the requested data is strictly necessary.

I tried to read carefully the documentation of `EasyThread` and of `Runnable`, but I didn't understand how to handle this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a thread you could easily use `Thread.sleep(1000)` or more simply `Util.sleep(1000)` which just swallows the `InterruptedException`. So something like this would work:

```
while(!isAllDataFetched) {
    if (serverAPI.getSomething() && serverAPI.getXXX() && ...) {
        isAllDataFetched = true;
    } else {
        Log.p("Connection ERROR in fetching initial data");
        Util.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works!!! Thank you, I supposed a more complex solution, instead it was so easy! ;-)